# How can I place vertices on the very center of the uv image?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

[image: example]

I am trying to move the selected vertices to slap onto the very center of the image, the resolution is 1000x1000 so I want it on the 500px mark. When I tried to center it myself I noticed that the black color on the right was starting to "leak" on to the edge as shown here, kind of hard to see but it's those black spots

[image: leak]

Comment: I would pop that image into the Gimp and crop it to the exact size you need. There will be workarounds that others have mentioned, but setting up your textures to what you need is always easiest and cleanest. Then from a set view choose UV Mapping-->Project from view(bounds), and let Blender do all the hard work for you.

Comment: Ron Proctor's solution, but just set 0.5 0.5 instead of 500 for selected vertices,
Shouldn't that work as well?

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better way, but here's a quick and dirty method:

- In the UV/Image editor, select all vertices.
- In the UV/Image editor's <kbd>N</kbd>-panel, set the UV vertex position to X: 500; Y: 500.
- With all vertices still selected, scale 50% in the x-direction by tapping <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, then typing ".5", <kbd>Return</kbd>.
- In the N-panel, set the UV vertex position to X: 250.

Answer (score 2):

In 3d-view in edit mode select your plane and set view in front of your plane  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> or any standard view if your plane isn't rotated in 3d-space

Then press <kbd>U</kbd> -> `Project from view (bounds)`

It will create UV-layout that fits perfectly of image bounds.